# Preventting bots from submitting forms (link) is this overkill?

Tags: php, form-submit

Currently I just use a hidden text field and check to see if it gets filled. The theory is if its been filled then a bot must have done it because it's hidden and the user would never be able to fill it.

I found this [article](http://jasonlau.biz/home/php/catching-automated-form-submissions-and-trapping-spam-bots) detailing how to stop bots from auto submitting forms. It creates a form and uses CSS to hide it `left: 1000px; top: 1000px;` then actually adds the IP of the bot to the htaccess file to effectively ban the bot.

The second method seems a bit overkill especially since it could pollute your .htaccess file. Is my method adequate? Is the second appropriate?

Comment: It sounds gimmicky to me, isn't captcha enough for your site? you get a lot of bots?

Comment: I've used your method several times and it has always worked well enough for me and doesn't force your users to use a captcha ( annoying and not foolproof ).

Comment: @emartel: Actually I'm still in development and I'm researching many things one of them being preventing spambots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems sound, but adding the IP address to .htaccess is overkill and I wouldn't particularly recommend it. The file would grow unmanageably large pretty quickly, and banning bots/spammers by IP is like herding cats.

Honestly though, the best captcha is one of the simplest: Ask a question and expect a human response.

> What color is the sky? *_*_
>
> What is the second word in the title of this page? *_*_

Just avoid putting up math questions since most bots these days will check for things like that.

Comment: Actually this give me a great idea: adding a table with several human questions and their answers and randomly choosing a question to ask. Thanks for this.